# Busybox 1.23 proto option not working in ip link command

Tags: protocols, busybox, vlan, proto

I try to issue this command on an ARM box with busybox installed:
ip link add link eth0 eth0.100 type vlan proto 802.1q id 100

I get an error:
argument of "protocol" must be "on" or "off"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got the same problem with busybox 1.23. I issued a bug on busybox bug tracking system. I also propose a solution that can help you.

The bug is at:

https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=8261

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

I've tested IP commands in busybox-1.27.2 and it works fine in this version.

Former version in my router - busybox-1.26.2 has this error.

Comment: This should be a comment not, it's not an answer :)